# Deleting certain things in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text in Notepad++ similar to this:

```
176106024 one.html
176106024 one_files
176116365 work completed.docx
176116365 condition rept.html
176116365 condition rept_files
176119671   re-open.htm
176119671   re-open _files
176119671 re-open .html
176119671 re-open 
176123433 Debris.html
176123433 Debris_files
```

I have to delete everything except numbers and be left with this:

```
176106024 
176106024 
176116365 
176116365 
176116365 
176119671   
176119671   
176119671 
176119671 
176123433 
176123433
```

Could you advise me how to do this? Much appreciated. Text is different in every line, rarely repeats.

Comment: Hi, did any of the provided answers solve your problem? If one or more did, you should select one and mark it as the answer to close out this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, regular expressions. It's a radio button option for searches.

Try Find & Replace with

`(^\d{1,}).*?$`

And replace it with

`$1`

This is the regex breakdown provided by RegexBuddy:

> "`(`" +             // Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number **1** `/* This is why we are using $1 in Notepad++ */`
>
> "`^`" +             // Assert position at the beginning of the string
>
> "`\\d`" +            // Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only)
>
> "`{1,}`" +          // Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) "`)`" +
>
> "`.`"  // Match any single character
>
> "`*?`" +            // Between zero and
>   unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
>
> "`$`"               // Assert position at the end of the string, or
>   before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed)

Basically, we're using the capture inside of the parentheses as a backreference in the replace. It matches the whole line, but only replaces it with what you want (the numbers). Please let me know if its only numbers, or alpha-numeric.

Comment: You could also simply use `\d+` instead of `\d{1,}`

Comment: Thank you, @DominicComtois! That's a great alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regular expressions, you can hold down the `ALT` key and click and drag to select as columns. Then you can just copy out what you want into another file or perform any other task you would do with selected text.

[image]

Comment: That's elegant AF! xD I like it. The only problem I can see cropping up with this is number sets without matching character lengths. If OP knows that they will always be the same width and doesn't mind doing it manually per-file, this is a solid answer.

Comment: Yep, that's the only real drawback is unaligned data, but in that case - yes, regexp is the way to go. However, I would prefer to use this method if at all possible. You can do this in Notepad++ as well as MultiEdit. There may be a few other editors out there that do this, but those are the two main ones I know of.

Comment: It did not word for me, maybe because numbers are different or I am doing something wrong...

Comment: What version of `Notepad++` are you using. Not sure when that feature was added, but it *could* be an issue... The content of the file doesn't make a difference. The only thing that could cause a problem using column select is text allignment, however that wouldn't prevent you from using this method, It would just cause some issues with not being able to select a straight column. Which, that is just an issue with alignment, not functionality. Hold the `ALT` key while you `Left-Click-Hold` and drag a select box, just like you would when you click and drag for a single line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Do a regex replace of `[ ].*$` with an empty string.